# Move uploaded files by form field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to move documents (images/videos) uploaded through a Google form to newly created folder. There are 4 form fields accepting different documents, say Front, Back, Left, and Right fields. I use the code from [labnol](https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226), but I don't know how to further modify the code to move and group the documents by the field name inside the target folder.

Below is my current code. The code is triggered upon form submission.

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '**********************';
const strFrontFolderName = 'Front View Photos';
const strBackFolderName = 'Back View Photos';
const strRightFolderName = 'Right View Photos';
const strLeftFolderName = 'Left View Photos';

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  var objForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var arrFormResponses = objForm.getResponses();
  var arrItemResponses = arrFormResponses[arrFormResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  var dteVisitDate = arrItemResponses[0].getResponse();
  dteVisitDate = new Date(dteVisitDate);
  var strVisitDate = Utilities.formatDate(dteVisitDate, "GMT+07:00", "yyyyMMdd");
  var strProjectName = arrItemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var strProjectFolderName = strVisitDate + '-' + strProjectName;

  // Prepare the folders.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  const projectFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(strProjectFolderName);
  const roofFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strFrontFolderName);
  const roadFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strBackFolderName);
  const brokenFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strRightFolderName);
  const stackingFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strLeftFolderName);
    
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD')
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        //DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

P.S.:
As additional information, the ultimate goal of this project is I would like to be able to push the information to google slide and put the data and the photos on the correct slide.

**EDIT:**

I find the following approach seems to work. I like this approach because it's easier to understand but is it a good approach?

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '**********************';
const strFrontFolderName = 'Front View Photos';
const strBackFolderName = 'Back View Photos';
const strRightFolderName = 'Right View Photos';
const strLeftFolderName = 'Left View Photos';

const onFormSubmit(e) {
  var objForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var arrFormResponses = objForm.getResponses();
  var arrItemResponses = arrFormResponses[arrFormResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  var dteVisitDate = arrItemResponses[0].getResponse();
  dteVisitDate = new Date(dteVisitDate);
  var strVisitDate = Utilities.formatDate(dteVisitDate, "GMT+07:00", "yyyyMMdd");
  var strProjectName = arrItemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var strProjectFolderName = strVisitDate + '-' + strProjectName;

  // Prepare the folders.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  const projectFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(strProjectFolderName);

  var arrFieldIndex = [2,3,4,5]
  var arrFolders = splitText("Front View Photos,Back View Photos,Right View Photos,Left View Photos",",")

  for (var i = 0; i < arrFieldIndex.length; i++) {
    var intField = arrFieldIndex[i];
    if (arrItemResponses[intField]) {
      var objPictureFolder = objProjectFolder.createFolder(arrFolders[i].toString());
      var arrFiles = splitText(arrItemResponses[intField].getResponse().toString(),",");
      Logger.log("arrFiles" + ": " + arrFiles );
      arrFiles.forEach(function(value,index) {
          Logger.log(index + ": " + value );
          DriveApp.getFileById(value.toString()).moveTo(objPictureFolder);
        });
    }
  }
};


function splitText(strText,strSeparator) {
  var varArray = [{}];
   varArray = strText.split(strSeparator);
   return varArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want each of the files in the upload fields to be moved to the particular folder that the file corresponds to (depending on the field from which it was uploaded).

Please try the below and replace the keys ('First file', 'Second file' etc.) in the variable `subfolders`with the actual titles of your Google Form file fields.

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '**********************';
const strFrontFolderName = 'Front View Photos';
const strBackFolderName = 'Back View Photos';
const strRightFolderName = 'Right View Photos';
const strLeftFolderName = 'Left View Photos';

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  var objForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var arrFormResponses = objForm.getResponses();
  var arrItemResponses = arrFormResponses[arrFormResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  var dteVisitDate = arrItemResponses[0].getResponse();
  dteVisitDate = new Date(dteVisitDate);
  var strVisitDate = Utilities.formatDate(dteVisitDate, "GMT+07:00", "yyyyMMdd");
  var strProjectName = arrItemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var strProjectFolderName = strVisitDate + '-' + strProjectName;

  // Prepare the folders.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  const projectFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(strProjectFolderName);
  const roofFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strFrontFolderName);
  const roadFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strBackFolderName);
  const brokenFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strRightFolderName);
  const stackingFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(strLeftFolderName);
  var subfolders = {
    "First file": roofFolder,
    "Second file": roadFolder,
    "Third file": brokenFolder,
    "Fourth file": stackingFolder
  }
    
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD')
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    const fieldNames = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD')
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getTitle())
    
    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      files.forEach((fileId,index) => {
        var subfolder = subfolders[fieldNames[index]]
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.

There are 2 things: 1) it doesn't move files to the correct destination folders. 2) it doesn't process all of the uploaded files.

It seems like it moves files from first field to each of the 4 target folders and doesn't process the files received in the next fields.